# Recording data, entering data in the command line, and limiting the length of integers

Tags: java, class, object, command-line

I have to write a program that models an employee. The employee has an employee number, a first and last name, an address consisting of a street, a city, a state, and a 5-digit zip code, and a hire date consisting of a month, a day, and a year. It must use an employee class, a name class, an address class, and a date class. Each class must record information that it entered by the user. Here is what I have written:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class AssignmentTen
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {   
        System.out.println();       

        int input1 = getInt ("Enter Employee Number:");
        Employee e1 = new Employee(input1);
        System.out.println("#" + e1.number);

        String input2 = getString ("Enter Employee First Name:");
        String input3 = getString ("Enter Employee Last Name:");
        Name n1 = new Name(input2, input3);
        System.out.println(n1.firstName + " " + n1.lastName);

        String input4 = getString ("Enter Employee Street:");
        String input5 = getString ("Enter Employee City:");
        String input6 = getString ("Enter Employee State (Initials):");
        int input7 = getInt ("Enter Employee Zip Code (5 Digits):");
        Address a1 = new Address (input4, input5, input6, input7);
        System.out.println(a1.eStreet + " " + a1.eCity + " " + a1.eState + " " + a1.eZipCode);

        int input8 = getInt ("Enter Employee Hire Month (MM):");
        int input9 = getInt ("Enter Employee Hire Day (DD):");
        int input10 = getInt ("Enter Employee Hire Year(YYYY):");
        Date d1 = new Date (input8, input9, input10);
        System.out.println("Hire Date: " + d1.month + "/" + d1.day + "/" + d1.year);
    }

    public static int getInt(String paramString)
    {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(paramString);
        return Integer.parseInt(str);
    }

    public static String getString(String paramString)
    {
        String str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(paramString);
        return str;
    }
}

class Employee
{
    int number;

    Employee(int newNumber)
    {
        number = newNumber;
    }
}

class Name
{
    String firstName;
    String lastName;

    Name(String first, String last)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
    }
}

class Address
{
    String eStreet;
    String eCity;
    String eState;
    int eZipCode;

    Address(String street, String city, String state, int zipCode)
    {
        eStreet = street;
        eCity = city;
        eState = state;
        eZipCode = zipCode;
    }
}

class Date
{
    int month;
    int day;
    int year;

    Date(int eMonth, int eDay, int eYear)
    {
        month = eMonth;
        day = eDay;
        year = eYear;
    }
}
```

However, I still have a few more things I need that I am not sure how to implement. My question is how can I:

- Make the state string not display anything that is longer or shorter than two letters
- Make the zip code variable in the Address class only display the first five characters of any inputs that are longer than five characters
- Be able to store data for multiple Employees
- Be able to specify how many employees information will be stored for in the command line
- Store all of the information for a single employee in another class, and make objects for each employee containing all of their information

Any help or advice on how I can clean up my code will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, classes `Date, Name, Address` should be used as fields of `Employee`. Also consider variable names like `zipCode` instead of `input7`.

> Be able to store data for multiple Employees

You can store Employees in a Collection, Set for instance:

```
 Set<Employee> employess = new HashSet<>(); // field
 ...
 employess.add(e1);
```

> Be able to specify how many employees information will be stored for in the command line

```
int howmany = getInt ("Howmany emp you want to put");
for(int i = 0 ; i < howmany; i++) {
    //invoke here extracted method getting all employee data
    //example: employees.add(getEmployeeData());
}
```

> Store all of the information for a single employee in another class, and make objects for >each employee containing all of their information

After putting Date,Name and Address into Employee problem will be solved i guess.

> Make the zip code variable in the Address class only display the first five characters of >any inputs that are longer than five characters

```
int input7 = getInt ("Enter Employee Zip Code (5 Digits):"); //wrong varible name!
String zipCode = String.valueOf(input7);
if(zipCode.lenght() > 5) {
    zipCode= zipCode.subString(0,4);
}
```

> Make the state string not display anything that is longer or shorter than two letters

```
String input6 = getString ("Enter Employee State (Initials):");
if(input6.lenght != 2) {
     input6 = "";
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the response, but this isn't quite what I'm looking for. Making Date, Name, and Address fields of Employee sounds like a good idea, but I'm coding this for an assignment; the parameters of which specify that they all must be in separate classes. I also am not familiar with collections and I cannot use them in my program. Finally, I need a way for the amount of employees to be specified when the program is launched, and not through an input window. Thanks again for your input though.

Comment: so pass employee amount as a argument to java program and: `if(args.lenght != 1) {System.exit(0);} else {int howMany = Integer.parseString(args[0]);}`. instead of Collections you can store Employees in Array -> `Employee[] employyes = new Employee[howMany](); ... employyes[i] = new Employee(...);`. If you dont want to put this classes into EMployee just create `EmployeeData` or something similar that contains all of them.

Comment: If you dont know how to pass program argument in java take a look on http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html. And Arrays tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Comment: @smaljo I typed in what you said for making the zip code only accept 5 digits or less, and I keep getting 'error: cannot find symbol'. It looks like [this:](http://pastebin.com/JTHkk5fC)

Comment: @smaljo Same thing with your bit for the state string.

Comment: there was 2 typos: `if(input6.length() != 2)` and `zipCode = zipCode.substring(0,4);` - those are correct forms